# How to update global variable after http call Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a global variable which I need to update after http get call. After update I need to pass this updated variable to other function. I can't understand what is the best way to do this. Here is my code:

```
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     var data = '';
     $http.get("data.json")
       .then(function(response) {
        data = response.data;
     });
     vm.mapOptions = {
        controls: {
            navigator: false
        },
        center: [40, -35],
        zoom: 3,
        layers: [{
            style: {
                fill: {
                    color: '#1996E4'
                },
                stroke: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                }
            },
            type: 'shape',
            dataSource: data
        }],
        shapeCreated: onShapeCreated,
        shapeFeatureCreated: onShapeFeatureCreated
    };
    });
```

Is it possible at all to update global variable after http call?

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: This will probably be an issue with whatever vm is.  Your code should update the dataSource, but are you sure vm would "rerender" if that data source changed?

Comment: You can console.log(data) to see if its value changes when you expect.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  In general, you should use services rather than "global variables".  also, you aren't showing where you are declaring `vm` here, or how `dataSource` is used, but since you declared `data` as a primitive string, it's likely to not work as expected, especially since `response.data` appears to be JSON....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a http request, it takes some time to send the request and get the response, specially when you send the request to a API on a server,but in meanwhile the execution continues immediately and the statement after your http call is executed and if you have something that depends on the response, most properly will be failed.

in your case `vm.mapOptions` have dependency to `data`, which is a local variable getting the respnse from get request. so what can you do?

Step 1  :

make a function for all codes that are involve with your response :

```
$scope.myCallBack = function(data){
  vm.mapOptions = {
    controls: {
        navigator: false
    },
    center: [40, -35],
    zoom: 3,
    layers: [{
        style: {
            fill: {
                color: '#1996E4'
            },
            stroke: {
                color: '#FFFFFF'
            }
        },
        type: 'shape',
        dataSource: data
    }],
    shapeCreated: onShapeCreated,
    shapeFeatureCreated: onShapeFeatureCreated
   };

}
```

Step 2  : 
Call the myCallBack function inside your $http.get right after getting the response

```
var data = '';
 $http.get("data.json")
   .then(function(response) {
    data = response.data;
    $scope.myCallBack(data);
 });
```